# I have a list of searching word. How to replace them in another file?

Tags: notepad++, regex, sed, find-and-replace, awk

I'm sure this question is asked multiple times, but I fail to find it. Basically I have a text file, and a list of all search strings (e.g. `cat`, `dog`, `banana`, etc). I want all occurrences of those strings in the text file be replaced to `<span class="hello">$1</span>`. I know a scripting language like Python can handle this, but is there a more lightweight solution, like Notepad++ or sed/awk only?

Comment: Is the word list long or only few words?

Comment: Quite long. Around 100 lines

Comment: Could you give us sample text, word file and expected result? Is Perl script an option?

Comment: "I have a text file". Please add it to your question (no comment here).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a batch file to make the job. Copy the following code into a text file and save it with the name that you want but with a ".bat" extension.

At the part "set Wordlist=" you should specify the path to your wordlist (search strings). Drag and drop the text file to the batch and it should create a new file with the same name as the old but a "_New" in the name...

```
@echo off

:: Please drag and drop the text file to this batch
if not exist "%~1" exit

:: Put the path to your wordlist here:
set WordList=Wordlist.txt

set FileN=%~n1

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%WordList%") do set /a TCounter+=1

for /f "usebackq eol= delims=" %%a in ("%~1") do for /f "usebackq eol= delims=" %%b in ("%WordList%") do call :Rename "%%a" "%%b"
exit

:Rename
IF "%Counter%"=="" set "Linha=%~1"
set /a Counter+=1
set "SWord=%~2"
echo %~1|find /i "%~2" 1>nul 2>nul
IF %Errorlevel% EQU 0 call set "Linha=%%Linha:%SWord%=<span class="hello">$1</span>%%"
IF %Counter% EQU %TCounter% (
                             for %%a in ("%Linha%") do >>"%FileN%_NEW.txt" echo %%~a 
                             set Counter=
                            )
goto :EOF
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When handling strings present in html codes, consider that you will need to handle any characters that will make it necessary to use escaping in a bat script...

For the lines you can use a `set /p`, and for the replacement I suggest using the `powershell -replace`:

```bat
@echo off

cd/d "%~dp0" & set "_rplc=<span class="hello">$1</span>"

for /f %%f in ('type .\"file_read.txt"^|findstr /r [.-a-Z-0-9] "file_edit.txt"^|find/v /c ""
')do set "_i=%%~f" & ((for /l %%L in (01, 01, %%~f)do set /p _find_%%~L=)<.\"file_read.txt")

for /l %%L in (01, 01, %_i%)do if defined _find_%%~L >.\"file_edited.txt" (
    PowerShell -nOp -c "(gc ".\file_edit.txt" -raw).replace("$env:_find_%%~L","$env:_rplc")"
    ) & <con: copy /y .\"file_edited.txt" ".\file_edit.txt" >nul
```